# How to show three child tables side by side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to show three child tables side by side below selected TR.The child rows are aligned vertically below first column of parent TR. Can we place them below selected Column of parent TR?

Here is the code

```
    function format ( data ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table class="floatLeft">'+
        '<tr>'+
        "<td class='hide-elem'></td>"+
        "<td class='hide-elem'></td>"+
        "<td class='hide-elem'></td>"+
        "<td class='hide-elem'></td>"+
            '<td>START</td>'+
            '<td>data.serviceHrs</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>CURRENT</td>'+
            '<td>data.serviceType</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>SERVICE INTERVAL</td>'+
            '<td>data.serviceHrs</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
        '<td>ALERT Global.distance</td>'+
        '<td>data.serviceHrs</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '</table>'+ 

    '<table  class="floatRight">'+
    '<tr>'+
    "<td class='hide-elem'></td>"+
    "<td class='hide-elem'></td>"+
    "<td class='hide-elem'></td>"+
    "<td class='hide-elem'></td>"+
        '<td>START Global.distance</td>'+
        '<td>data.serviceHrs</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>CURRENT Global.distance</td>'+
        '<td>data.serviceType</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>SERVICE INTERVAL Global.distance</td>'+
        '<td>data.serviceHrs</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>ALERT Global.distance</td>'+
    '<td>data.serviceHrs</td>'+
'</tr>'+
'</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use the style

```
display: inline-block
```

this forces to tables to appear next to each other rather than underneath

then make sure there widths are set so they can all appear next to each other across the page

like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2tkkxe7/)

Comment: Can we show the table below specific column? for example, if a table has 8 rows, i need to show the child table below 6th row.

Comment: you may have to use `position: absolute` and define where you want them using `top` and `left` style properties manually